# Palindrome Seperating in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to separate a string based on palindrome. But my code splitting extra palindromes in my output what mistake I made?

example:
Input 1:

```
radarnoonlevel
```

Output 1:

```
radar noon level
```

Input 2:

```
malayalamdadmom
```

Output 2:

```
malayalam dad mom
```

My code:

```
s="radarnoonlevel"
ans=[]
for i in range(0,len(s)):
  for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
    if s[i]==s[j] and s[i:j+1]==s[i:j+1][::-1]:
      ans+=[s[i:j+1]]
print(*ans)
```

My output:

```
radar ada noon oo level eve
```

I tried to separate a string based on palindrome. But my code splitting strings with extra palindromes in my output what mistake I made?

Comment: You are iterating through each letter in the string, and technically ada and oo are palindromes. So your algorithm is finding them for you. Your code is working as intended, if you want to specify which words to find I think that's a different question.

Comment: Yeah but if the problem is seen as the fewest, longest, possible palindromes then we are back to OP’s original formulation though their code wont work for reason stated.

Comment: Like others mentioned, for `radar`, you need to only print `radar` but also print `ada`, which is the only issue. I suggest you separate the parsing and palindrome checks into two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly fix the indentation in the function after line 1 (def func(s)). I am not able to properly format it here. I hope the algorithm here helps you.

```
def break_palin(s):
i = 1
j = 0
mylist = []
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == s[j]:
        mylist.append(s[j:i+1])
        j = i + 1
        i = i + 2
    else:
        i += 1
return ' '.join(mylist)
```